# unable to deploy post deploy hooks on dokku

Tags: dokku

I have deployed an application using Dokku. This application runs a python script.
As a dependency for this python script, I want to install a python module once the application is deployed. To achieve that, I have installed a post-deployment hooks plugin.
[I have installed this dokku plugin to do this](https://github.com/mlomnicki/dokku-deploy-hooks)

My post-deploy plugin (script) contains only this command:
    `pip3 install lark-parser`

However it's throwing access denied error on deployment.
Any idea what i am missing here?

Output of the git push dokku master:

```
-----> Running post-deploy
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.postdeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> Running post-deploy hooks
-----> /app/post-deploy
remote: setuidgid: fatal: unable to run /app/post-deploy: access denied
```